# How can I reenable Gmail notifications after disabling them through Inbox?

Tags: notifications, gmail, inbox-by-gmail

I used to have both Inbox and Gmail installed. This meant duplicate notifications. Inbox had the option "Turn off Gmail notifications" which I had selected. Since then, Inbox has become defunct and I haven't been able to figure out how to undo that.

Crucially: all of my Gmail and Android settings turn notifications from Gmail on, but they still won't show up. Does anyone know what Inbox did and how I can undo it?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Have you tried clearing Gmail cache? Clear its data?

Comment: I could have sworn I tried this... I tried again and it works ‍♂️. Thanks!

Comment: Should I write it as an answer?

Comment: Please do, and I'll accept!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have removed Inbox app, but the issue remains. If Inbox did modified Gmail settings, then you have to tried the "usual" steps:

- Clear Gmail's cache.
- Clear Gmail's data (this step also clears the cache): It will reset the app to default. You will have to login again to your account as you did the first time you used the app.
- Remove and re-install Gmail (if it was not installed by default like in some custom ROMs).
- Remove all Gmail updates (it will allow Gmail to return to the state it had when you bought the device).